# Why do I get a Bad request when I run server.js and client.js and access localhost?

Tags: javascript, node.js, faye

I am new to node.js

I am trying to use the pub/sub faye nodemodule to create a publish/subscribe web application.

I have the following files and folders: My dependencies in the node_modules folder, a sever.js file, and a client.js

My server.js contains the following code:

```
var http = require('http'),
faye = require('faye');

var server = http.createServer(),
bayeux = new faye.NodeAdapter({mount: '/'});

bayeux.attach(server);
server.listen(8000);
```

As for my client.js file, it contains the following code:

```
var faye = require('faye')
var client = new faye.Client('http://localhost:8000/');

client.subscribe('/messages', function(message) { 
alert('Got a message: ' + message.text); 
});

client.publish('/messages', {
text: 'HAI!'
})
```

I go to my terminal and run node server.js and node client.js

When I go to my browser and run localhost:8000, all I get is a Bad request.

Why am I getting this? I am suspecting I don't have any page to display something.
Could someone please point out to me what I am missing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that error because you've mounted Faye at `/`. So if you try browsing to `/`, the server is expecting a Faye client, not a normal HTTP request.

There is a [browser client example](http://faye.jcoglan.com/browser.html) that shows how to connect with Faye mounted at `/faye`. You can also pass in a `request` handler into `http.createServer()` that allows you to handle the request before Faye does, in case you want to respond to the particular request.

Comment: so server.js will fire up the server. Now for the browser client example, I will have to have some html file to connect the client(using the script src='...') and display on the screen?

Comment: Yes. You might be able to get away with just loading that html file locally, otherwise you will have to serve the html and javascript files from the http server (using a request handler like I previously mentioned).